# iOS Game Center "alias" returns blank?

Tags: ios, game-center, gamekit

I'm making a "setup" page for a game app, and for convenience I'd like to prompt users with their Game Center username as a default.  That way they can change it if they'd like, but if they use the same screenname for everything, they won't have to type it in.

I thought it would be pretty simple, here's the code I worked up:

```
GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
[_textfieldUsername setText:localPlayer.alias];
```

...but it just returns a blank field.  Thing is, I know all my imports and syntax and such are correct, because if I change `alias` to `displayName`...

```
GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
[_textfieldUsername setText:localPlayer.displayName];
```

...it successfully populates the field with "Me."

I've confirmed that I have a Game Center alias ("Nerrolken") and I've tried the "Nintendo solution" of deleting that alias and re-entering it in Settings > Game Center.  It still returns "Me" for `displayName` and nothing at all for `alias`.

Am I missing something here?  How do you get the current player's Game Center username?

Comment: Is the player authenticated at this point?

Comment: Call "userID = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].alias];"